# (Python) Rtree intersection and fiona questions

Tags: python, r-tree, fiona

I'm trying to create a function for an intersection where the input file is of some urban area, and a query box is used to create an output file that has the intersection containing just the buildings found in that query box.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import fiona
import fiona.crs
import rtree


input_file = 'se_england_clean.shp'
out_file = 'se_england_out'
file_index = 'Rtree_index_east.idx'

query_box = [-0.0957870483,51.5134165224,-0.08664608,51.5192383994]



def write_clipped_file(name_file_in, out_file, file_index):
 idx = rtree.index.Index(file_index)
 idx.insert(0, (input_file))
 list(idx.intersection((query_box)))[0]
 count = 0
 with fiona.open(input_file, 'w') as out_file :  #?
    for building in out_file: #?
```

No idea if my code is right so far, but I have two immediate problems: 
First, I don't know how to open with Fiona the input shapefile and the new (clipped) shapefile that I want to produce in output. I want to cycle the list of indices, select the desired buildings, and write them in the new file 'out_file'. Second, I get an error:

```
 RTreeError: Coordinates must be in the form (minx, miny, maxx, maxy)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
idx.insert(0, (input_file))
```

You need to insert *coordinates* into the tree, not a file name.